# Using QGIS expression with overlay_nearest() function to create line connecting point to two nearest points of other layer

Tags: qgis, layers, expression, nearest-neighbor

I have in QGIS ver 3.22 two point layers named:

- source_p
- target_p

I want to point automatically with a line from the source_p layer to the two nearest points on the target_p layer.
Manually, I was able to generate such code where the target_p layer refers to the "parent" field in source_p layer.

```
make_line( 
  $geometry ,  
  geometry( 
    get_feature( 'target_p', 'fid' , parent  )
  )
)
```

Comment: Run `join attributes by nearest` adding the 2 closests points on your target layer to your source layer, then create the lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following expression with:

1. [array_foreach()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-foreach) (to create two lines) and
2. [collect_geometries()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#collect-geometries) to convert the array of lines to actual lines (geometries):

```
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            overlay_nearest (
                'target_p',  -- rename the layer if necessary
                $geometry,
                limit:=2
            ),
            make_line (
                $geometry,
                @element
            )
        )
    )
```

*The expression used on the `source_p` layer (red points) to create lines to the two nearest points from `targe_p` layer (blue dots):*
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me and exactly what I wanted