# Create line from point to two polygon centroids that meet a condition

Tags: qgis, polygon, expression, proximity, overlay

This is [this is a follow up to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/437727/175499)

I have in QGIS ver 3.22 two layers named:

- source_point_layer
- target_polygon_layer

I want to automatically point with a line from the source_point_layer to the center of two polygons that are no closer than 3000m and no further than 10000m with a value less than 7 on the target_polygon_layer
How to define min and max distance range?

Expression on "source_point_layer"

```
    collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        overlay_nearest (
            'target_polygon_layer',
            centroid($geometry),
            filter:="value"<'7',
            limit:=2,
            max_distance:=10000 -- how to define min_distance?
        ),
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try some thing like this.

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        array_slice(
            aggregate(
                layer:='target_polygon_layer',
                aggregate:='array_agg',
                expression:=centroid($geometry),
                filter:=distance(
                    geometry(@parent),
                    centroid($geometry)
                ) BETWEEN 3000 AND 10000
                AND to_real("value") < 7,
                order_by:=distance(
                    geometry(@parent),
                    centroid($geometry)
                )
            ),
            0,
            1
        ),
        make_line(
            @element,
            $geometry
        )
    )
)
```

The expression is very long so maybe you will need to adjust some parameters for your data. I suppose that you will use this expression in the [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool, otherwise you'll need to convert this to wkb or do something else to encode the geometry in a text field.

This is the output of the expression.
The polygons are labeled with their **value** attribute. I have added (in line 12) the [`to_real()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-real) function because I suspect that your field is a text type field, so you need to convert it into number and then the `< 7` will work. The lines are labeled with its length in meters (between 3000 and 10000)

[image: Modified geometries]